# MySQLI/PHP mysql_fetch_array() keeps missing first entry

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to fetch all "requestors" from a table and offer them as options in a form. As far as I know I didn't fetch the first row before but somehow my code misses the first entry.

Also when I submit the form and try to get the selected value with `$_POST` it doesn't take the selected value but instead takes the entry before that one.

Here is the code:

```
<select name="requestor">
             <option value="%">Please select Requestor</option>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
//============== check connection
if(mysqli_errno($con))
{
echo "Can't Connect to mySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
}
$logins = mysqli_query($con, "select Login_name from login");


while ($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($logins))
{
echo $dsatz["Login_name"]  . "<option value=". $dsatz["Login_name"]."</option>" . "<br />";
}

mysqli_close($con);                                         
?>
         </select>
```

Comment: Where are your form tags? Plus, you need to use the `$_POST` superglobal and assign it to a variable, which isn't in your post, but only a mention of. Why not show your full code instead of leaving it up to guesswork?

Comment: the form has 15 fields in which ppl chose their options and insert text. the variables get assigned in another php and then entered in a sql db.
can post you both codes if it helps

Comment: I usually like to see as much code related to a question as possible. it just leaves the guesswork out of things. Silly for some, but it works for me. Glad to see you found your solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
echo "<option value='".$dsatz["Login_name"]."'>".$dsatz["Login_name"].'"</option>";
```

within the loop

Comment: What about the other 50% of the question? *"Also when i submit the form and try to get the selected value with `$_POST` it doesen't take the selected value but the entry before that one."* - This is why I never put in answers for questions like these.

Comment: The other part will be fixed too.... i don't know his circumstances and i don't think i have to... he echoed some strange html structure that didn't make any sense... like this it is valid and his post will give the right data!

Comment: Fair enough. Now to wait for the OP's response ;)

Comment: great to help :) would you mark the answer usefull then? =)